# How to split an array into 28x28 dimension - getting wrong output

Tags: python, numpy

I need to define a function, that takes a csv file and divides it into 2 arrays: labels and images (pixel values). I managed to divide them into those arrays, I guess, but  have a problem splitting the pixel values into 28x28. My function look like this:

```
def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as training_file:
        training_file = np.loadtxt(training_file, delimiter=",", skiprows=1, dtype='str')
        labels = training_file[:, [0]]
        images = training_file[:, 1:784]
        images = np.array_split(images, 28)
        images = np.asarray(images)
        return images, labels
```

Then I call this function like this:

```
path_sign_mnist_train = f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2/sign_mnist_train.csv"
path_sign_mnist_test = f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2/sign_mnist_test.csv"
training_images, training_labels = get_data(path_sign_mnist_train)
testing_images, testing_labels = get_data(path_sign_mnist_test)
```

The expected output is this:

```
print(training_images.shape)
print(training_labels.shape)
print(testing_images.shape)
print(testing_labels.shape)

# Their output should be:
# (27455, 28, 28)
# (27455,)
# (7172, 28, 28)
# (7172,)
```

But instead I get this:

```
(28,)
(27455, 1)
(28,)
(7172, 1)
```

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Unrelated: `f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2"` is equivalent to `"../tmp2"`. See https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse140/13wi/file-interaction.html

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that.

Comment: [`array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) splits the array into the given number of sub-arrays about the given `axis` (default = 0) and  returns a list of those 28 sub-arrays. That's why `training_images` has a shape of `(28,)`. What is the shape of the elements of `training_images`? Do `print(training_images[0].shape)`

Comment: Here are some helpful links on debugging: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Rubber-duck debugging and stepping through your code are especially powerful tools to help you figure out why your code isn't working.

Comment: It gives me this `(981, 783)`. Do you know how to change my code so that I get the correct output? the columns from index 1 onwards are values between 0 and 255 which are pixel values. I need 28x28 for a picture in each row.

Comment: Final clarification: 28 * 28 = 784. Are you sure you meant `training_file[:, 1:784]` and not `training_file[:, 1:785]`? Remember that slices don't include the end index Alternatively, `training_file[:, 1:]` will give you all columns starting at the second column until the end.

Comment: You're right. it should be `[:, 1:785]`. The problem is it doesn't give me the desired `(27455, 28, 28)` but   `(28,)`
PS: thanks for debugging articles. I find them very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.array_split(x, 28)` will split your array into `28` sub-arrays along the zeroth axis (rows). So if `x` is of size `(2800, 10)`, you will get 28 arrays of size `(100, 10)`. You don't want this!

You seem to actually want to reshape each row of `training_file` into a `28x28` array. For that, you can use [`reshape()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). To demonstrate, I'm going to generate sample arrays that are a manageable size so that it's easy to understand. Let's say `training_file` has a shape of `(5, 10)`, and you want to convert each row of `training_file[:, 1:]` to a `3x3` array.

```
training_file = np.arange(50).reshape((5,10))
# this gives:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])

labels = training_file[:, 0] # this is irrelevant to the answer
images = training_file[:, 1:] # take all columns from idx 1-end
# this gives:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])

images_new = images.reshape((-1, 3, 3)) # reshape to shape (x, 3, 3) where x is as much as is required
# this gives:
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16],
        [17, 18, 19]],

       [[21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29]],

       [[31, 32, 33],
        [34, 35, 36],
        [37, 38, 39]],

       [[41, 42, 43],
        [44, 45, 46],
        [47, 48, 49]]])

images_new.shape
# this is:
(5, 3, 3)
```

So to answer your question: Instead of

```
images = training_file[:, 1:784]
images = np.array_split(images, 28)
images = np.asarray(images)
```

You want to do

```
images = training_file[:, 1:785]
images = images.reshape((-1, 28, 28))
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much! It obviously worked as desired. Before I read this I was searching the web and checking documentation of the functions I used and I got it that `np.array_split()` changes the array at `axis=0` by default, and then found `hsplit()` that splits the array horizontally, but I couldn't work out how to define that I want the first dimension to be the count of all rows in the array. I'll remember that `-1` can do that. Thank you, I've learnt a great deal from you.

Comment: Giving `-1` as the first dimension tells it "Do what you need to do to the first dimension to reshape this such that the other two are `28x28`". Keep in mind that it will still throw an error if your data can't be reshaped that way (for example, if you don't have an integer multiple of 28x28 elements in the array)

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks a lot, I'm very grateful for your help! I'm going back to learning. There's so much stuff left for me!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! You should accept the answer and upvote it so that other people can find it if they're stuck with a similar problem.